# Cannot get correct output

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to code a macro that will produce the number 8 in column C anytime there is a 1 in column A such as this:

Desired Output

[image]

My Current code is:

```vb
Sub STD()

For Each X In Range("A2:A7")

If X.Value = 1 Then 

Range("C2:C7").Value = 8

Else

End If

Next X

End Sub
```

However the output fills all of the range of column C with the number 8.

Current Output

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This line is causing the trouble `Range("C2:C7").Value = 8`. See if you can solve it yourself.

Comment: `Range(X).Value` selects all the cells in X, but you only need a single cell here, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the line `Range("C2:C7").Value = 8` with the following line

```vb
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x.Row, "C").Value = 8
```

, assuming the current worksheet is "Sheet1".

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit your line 
**Range("C2:C7").Value = 8** 
with 
**Cells(x.Row, "C").Value = 8**

Answer (score 0):

The cell with the result is located two column to the right of the X object.
Hence, one of the way to address that cell would be to use .OFFSET property as follow instead of using Range("C2:C7").Value = 8

```
For Each X In Range("A2:A7")
    If X.Value = 1 Then
        X.Offset(0, 2).Value = 8  
    Else
        X.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    End If
Next X
```